# Running a jar file at boot with cron and seeing output

Tags: bash, scripts, java, cron, reboot

I'm setting up a jar file to run at boot. I have a script to run it with, and that script is configured to run at boot in using @reboot in cron. I have a bare CLI interface for the moment, with no DEs. The question is how can I see the output from my script (and the jar it runs) as it runs in the CLI interface? It seems the script might be running from the background, and that might be the issue. How do I run it in the foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "run it in the foreground" at @reboot. You can capture STDOUT and STDERR in a log file (`man bash` see `REDIRECTION`).

You should be aware that the execution environment when @reboot stuff runs is even MORE restricted than the "normal" `cron` environment. Temporarily, add `env | sort >/tmp/cronjob.env` to the  beginning of your script (just after the shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`)), run it, then compare it with your usual environment's `env | sort >/tmp/normal.env`